# Looking for SQL to do a Sum of a Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm not a wiz when it comes to Subqueries. I'm trying to get the SQL script below to give the correct results, and with I'm doing something wrong, or I'm misinterpreting the results. Here is my SQL.

```
select Horizontal  Horizontal, sum(headcount)  Headcount, 
  sum(fte)  FTE, BE, Street, City, State, Zip, Country, 
  SQ_FT, O_L, Comp_Code, Entity
FROM
    (SELECT t.Horizontal Horizontal, 
        COUNT(d.SIGNEDAU) Headcount, 
        COUNT(d.SIGNEDAU) * t.[AU Distribution to Services] FTE, 
        a.[BE #] BE, d.ADDRESSLINE1 Street, d.CITY, 
        d.STATE, d.ZIP, d.COUNTRY,  
        a.FT2 SQ_FT, a.[O/L] O_L, a.[Comp Code], a.ENTITY
     FROM dbo.HR_Data d
        join dbo.Service_Taxonomy t
            ON d.SIGNEDAU = t.[AU Code] 
        left join dbo.All_Active a 
            ON d.CITY = a.City 
               AND d.STATE = a.ST 
               AND d.ADDRESSLINE1 = a.Street
     GROUP BY d.SIGNEDAU, t.[AU Distribution to Services], 
        a.[BE #], a.FT2, a.[O/L], a.[Comp Code],
        a.ENTITY, t.[Critical Y/N], t.Horizontal, t.[Level 1], 
        d.ADDRESSLINE1, d.CITY, d.STATE, d.COUNTRY, d.ZIP, 
        d.HR_STATUS, d.EMPLOYEESTATUS
     HAVING d.HR_STATUS = N'A' and d.EMPLOYEESTATUS = N'A') sub
Group by Horizontal, FTE, BE, Street, 
   City, State, Zip, Country, SQ_FT, 
   O_L, Comp_Code, Entity
```

[image]

I would expect the sum of Headcount and FTE, with the Group By, to merge these two rows into one, and yield a Headcount total of 10 and a FTE total of 5. For some reason, which I don't completely understand, the SQL above seems to NOT be summing and NOT be grouping. What am I missing?

Comment: You have pasted a screenshot of the output of your query, but it does not show the columns beyond Country. Can you provide a better screenshot, one that also includes SQ_FT, O_L, Comp_Code, Entity? Probably the rows differ in one of those columns.

Comment: The one thing I'll mention about subqueries (unless they're correlated, which your's is not) is to think of each subquery as its own distinct table. In other words, once you write a subquery, forget about all of its implementation details, and consider it as its own distinct relation. Then, performing aggregations against subqueries becomes an exercise like any other. If your subquery doesn't provide the right "starting material", rewrite it until it does. Then, again, forget it's implementation, and write your outer aggregation.

Comment: it will be easier for us to help you if you can post some sample data and the expected result

Comment: I guess the left join is the reason you are not getting the expected count (because of possible duplicate records). You can try putting a distinct inside the count to avoid duplicate counts. First check whether the counts returned by sub query are correct before taking the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude `FTE` from `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`